# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException thrown though there is only one implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

I have a `MyService` class which has `repository` field supposed to be injected.

```java
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;
// ...ommited
}
```

And there is `MyRepository` interface only implemented by `MyRepositoryImpl` class with `@Mapper annotation` of `MyBatis`.

```java
public interface MyRepository {
// ...ommited
}

@Mapper
public interface MyRepositoryImpl extends MyRepository {
// ...ommited
}
```

When I try to start SpringBootApplication, `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` is thrown.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
@MapperScan(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
(...omitted)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'com.example.MyService':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.MyRepository' available: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: com.example.MyRepositoryImpl,com.example.MyRepository
(...omitted)
```

Why is `MyRepository` interface registered as one of bean even though it doesn't have `@Component` annotation nor isn't included any bean configurations?

And I found that everything work fine if I don't use `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` as `nameGenerator`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many other ways to mark an interface as a bean. Some of them are:

1. @RepositoryDefinition above  MyRepository interface
2. MyRepository extends CrudRepository or JpaRepository

Check if any of these exist.

---

**Update 1:-**

The problem seems to be in `@MapperScan`. What it does is scans for all the interfaces in a package and register them as bean; and if I am not wrong `MyRepository` and `MyRepositoryImpl` are in the same package. That's the reason why 2 beans are being created with names `com.example.MyRepositoryImpl`, `com.example.MyRepository` and basically both are of same type as `MyRepositoryImpl` extends `MyRepository`. 
Now when you are using `@Autowired` on `repository` field of `MyService`, it gets confused as in which one to inject. To resolve this the easiest approach is to use `@Primary` over `MyRepositoy` which will give that interface a priority while injecting. Another approach is to use `@Qualifier("uniqueName")` over both the interfaces and also above `repository` field of `MyService` along with `@Autowired` specifying which one you want to inject. You can visit official documentation from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-primary) to learn more.
Hope this helps a bit .

Comment: You do not mark an interface as bean. @Repository is supposed to be put on the class RepositoryImpl.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, got confused. I am also new to this :D
I have edited the post. Other two are possible if I am not wrong.

Comment: I checked all of them don't exist around `MyRepository`. And the problem disappears after removing `nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` so the problem seems to be related to if I use `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` or not. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the update part and check if that works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Spring is not able to figure out the bean whose class is supposed to be implementing the Repository interface.
Put the annotation @Repository above the RepositoryImpl Class. It will find it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your it didn't work for me.
I think the interface annotated `@Mapper` annotation are recognized as a bean definition like `@Repository`. And the occuring exception is not `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` but `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` so I guess the problem is that both `MyReoisitory` interface and  `MyRepositoryImpl` class (generated by Mybatis) are registered as bean.
And the problem seems to be related to usage of `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator`.